# Adding an Android Test Device for Admob only works with ConsentDebugSettings.Builder().addTestDeviceHashedId

Tags: android, testing, admob

If I add an Android Test Device via ConsentDebugSettings.Builder().addTestDeviceHashedId with an ID in the form of "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" it works: I can see test ads in the app and AdRequest.isTestDevice is true.

For my client to be able to test, they need to be able to add test devices themselves, without me having access to Logcat or their physical devices. That's what "Add Test Devices" in Admob Dashboard -> Settings should be for right? When I try to add a test device by its advertising ID (in the form of "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx") it doesn't work, even after waiting a long time. Works for iOS devices btw.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known bug?